# /usr/bin/pkexec failed

Tags: permissions, ssh, pkexec

When I am creating an SSH public key and I'm prompted to enter my account's password the terminal returns

```
bash: line 2: .ssh/authorized_keys: Permission denied
```

When I open `authorized_keys` I cannot cannot manually save it;

```
Unable to save ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
Error: administrator_copy_file(/tmp/.subl36c.tmp, /home/lee/.ssh/authorized_keys) failed: /usr/bin/pkexec failed
```

Still new to Ubuntu; using a pre-existing install with unknown history.

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY gedit
```

returns:

```
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper: Success
```

Comment: Can you run `sudo echo hello`?

Comment: sudo works a-ok.

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/` give you?

Comment: `total 304
  -rwxr-xr-- 1 lee lee 310800 Nov 25  2014 dbus-daemon-launch-helper`

Comment: Why the heck does this thing belong to you? Please run `sudo chown root:messagebus /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper && sudo chmod 4754 /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper`

Comment: I wish I knew, been chasing ghosts on this thing since I got it last week. I changed the ownership back to what it was supposed to be; pkexec still fails to save my sshd_config file, and I cannot add anything to .ssh/known_hosts either. 

I had to superuser the ownership of sudo back to root earlier, and my cups log file kept filling up infinitely large until I manually stopped the service. The permissions of most folders seem right, but some things are waay off.



The problem is probably more ubiquitous than I make it sound though.

Comment: What do the permissions and ownerships in `/usr/lib` in general tell you?

Comment: everything in /usr/lib is owned by me, I checked a couple dozen folders. and files. the permissions still seem to be correct (as far as I can tell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the comments: Many file and directory ownerships in the system are broken (owned by the main user instead of e.g. root, wrong permissions). Your system is more or less broken. In what ways did the previous owner abuse this system?

You can try to find out what the default ownerships and permissions are, and set them manually; there is no way to reset all ownerships and permissions automatically. I wish you the all the fun in the world would you choose to do so.

Alternatively, reinstall the system. Only by doing so you can be sure that any digital crimes committed to this computer by the previous owner are rooted out. That way, you'll have a clean, recent and properly owned system. You can get Ubuntu installation images from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop); installation instructions can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation). ***Create a backup*** of all your personal files before reinstalling the system.

Comment: Yeah this was pretty much what I expected. Thanks for the information.